# How to order by amount of related objects in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have two models, a `User` model and a `Post` model, the `Post` model has a `ref` field that references the `User` model, I don't want to create an embedded `Post` schema within the `User` schema.

I want to order the `User`s by the amount of `Post`s they have, how would I do this in mongoose/and or node mongo driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without and example of your schema is not easy to know what exactly you want but I think this is you need:

First of all, it will be easier if in your `User` schema you have an array of `_id's` from the total number of comments. Because in this way you won't be `$lookup`.

But, you can use this query:

- First `$lookup` to join both collections. In this first stage you create a field called `post` where there are the joined data.
- Then `$set` to replace the value for the size (i.e. how many posts has the user)-
- And last `$sort` to get data sorted.

```js
db.User.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Post",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "user",
      "as": "post"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {"post": {"$size": "$post"}}
  },
  {
    "$sort": {"post": -1}
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/l_uRnz1b9_C)

Comment: is there a way to do this in mongoose itself?

Comment: Is exactly the same query. Only take care with your collection name. I think mongoose recall collection to `posts`. But the query is exactly the same, you can execute in mongoose using: `yourModel.aggregate( /*query here*/).then(res => {console.log(res)})`

Comment: Is there a way that I could filter the posts based on a field value, and only limit to get the first 5 users instead of all of them?

Comment: Yes, add a stage `$match` to filter and `$limit: 5` to get only 5. Check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fUmfngrfqdu)

Comment: I want to filter the sessions being counted, not the users, how would I do that

Comment: Then use `"$match": {"post": your_filter_here}`